# Passing cshtml field value to url.action through jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to call an action in my controller passing parameters via routeValues. I know how to do it with literals, but I can't do it using the field values on the current page.
I've tried the following approaches:

```
$('#btnAdmDel').click(function () {
                    $.get('@Url.Action("deleteAdm", "SuperUser", new {id=$('#tbSeek').val()  })', function (data) {
                        $('#partials').html(data);
                    });
                });
```

But this won't work because it says that '#btnAdmDel' has too many characters, since it understands it as c# code and `char` variable have only one character. Then I tried this:

```
$('#btnAdmDel').click(function () {
                    $.get('@Url.Action("deleteAdm", "SuperUser", new {id=$("#tbSeek").val() })', function (data) {
                        $('#partials').html(data);
                    });
                });
```

Same code, but changed the apostrophes to quotation marks, changing the `char` to a `string`, but then it says that the '$' right before it, is an unexpected character. So I tried this:

```
$('#btnAdmDel').click(function () {
                    var param = $('#tbSeek').val();
                    $.get('@Url.Action("deleteAdm", "SuperUser", new {id=param})', function (data) {
                        $('#partials').html(data);
                    });
                });
```

Now I'm trying to pass the value through a variable, `param`, but it says that the name `param` is not known in that context.

I'm sure there must be a way to do this, but I don't seem to grasp how to. Just to clarify it, I'm trying to use the text value from the input as a `routeValue` in the `deleteAdm` action.
Help please. Thanks.

---

Edit:
Forgot to mention, the field I'm trying to acess is not on the actual page I'm in, but in the partial view that is loaded afterwards, as is the button that I'm clicking, I don't know if this helps.

---

View code:

```
@model pedidosOnlineMVC.Models.SuperUser
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MySystem";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Administration</h2>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@using(var p = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Panel()))
{   
    using (p.BeginBody())
    {
        @Html.Bootstrap().Button().Text("Register new  administrator").Id("btnReg")
        @Html.Bootstrap().Button().Text("List administrators").Id("btnList")
        @Html.Bootstrap().Button().Text("Search administrator").Id("btnSeek")   
        using (var ip = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Panel()))
        {
            using (ip.BeginBody())
            {
                <div id="partials">
                </div>
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Partial View code:

```
@model IEnumerable<pedidosOnlineMVC.Models.Administrator>
@using (var t = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Table()))
{
    using (var h = t.BeginHeader())
    {
        using(var hr = h.BeginHeaderRow())
        {
            @hr.Cell("Name")
            @hr.Cell("Registration")
            @hr.Cell("Phone")
            @hr.Cell("Establishment")
            @hr.Cell("Select")
            @hr.Cell("Delete")
        }
    }
    foreach (var adm in Model)
    {
        using (var r = t.BeginRow())
        {
            @r.Cell(adm.name)
            @r.Cell(adm.reg)
            @r.Cell(adm.phone)
            if (adm.est!=null)
            {
                @r.Cell(adm.est.name)
            }
            else
            {
                @r.Cell("")
            }
            @r.Cell(Html.Bootstrap().Button().Text("Select").Id("btnAdmSelect"))
            @r.Cell(Html.Bootstrap().Button().Text("Delete").Id("btnAdmDel")).Data(new { del = adm.Administrator_Id})
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the way the code was, so now i get the data value from the button clicked. The java script is now this:

```
$('#btnAdmDel').click(function () {
                        $.get(@Url.Action("deleteAdm", "SuperUser")+'?id='+$('#btnAdmDel').data('del'), function (data) {
                            $('#partials').html(data);
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: Please share the view and partial view code.

Comment: Just used Chrome's debugger and it seems like the script is not being reached, as in, the event doesn't fire. The click events from the buttons on the actual view are firing normally...
Perhaps I should put the script on the partial view file?

Comment: That didn't work. Now I'm desperate.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. So you're saying `$("#btnAdmDel").click()` is not firing?

Comment: Exactly. Neither is any other button that came with the partial view.

Comment: Try `$("body").on("click", "#btnAdmDel", function(e){ ... });`. It is a jQuery delegate issue.

Comment: Didn't work. I actually tried a lot of variations on calling the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass a value from javascript to a method run in Razor, because the razor code is run on the server before the page is rendered, and javascript code is run on the client. This means you can't directly pass the javascript value to the razor method, but to accomplish what you want, you can build the link without the parameter in razor, then append it in javascript when you need to:

```
$('#btnAdmDel').click(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("deleteAdm", "SuperUser")' + '?id=' + $('#tbSeek').val(), function (data) {
        $('#partials').html(data);
    });
});
```

The razor code is run before the page is rendered, so you'll get something like this if you view source (rendered page):

```
$('#btnAdmDel').click(function () {
    $.get('http://example.com/SuperUser/deleteAdm' + '?id=' + $('#tbSeek').val(), function (data) {
        $('#partials').html(data);
    });
});
```

And then when the click event is fired, it appends `?id=` and the value to the url to get. It's critical that you understand the execution time of both Razor and JavaScript code.

Comment: I understood the concept of the different execution times between them. You're saying that the Razor code is run when I "compile" the project, and the javascript code is run when the page loads in the browser. The source code is exactly like you said in the browser, but the action method is not being executed.

Comment: @guilofrano No, the razor code is not run when you compile the project. It's executed at run time when the view is rendered. If this isn't working, you've got some other issue. Is the `deleteAdm` method marked with an `HttpPost` Attribute? If so, you won't be able to hit it with a `GET` request.

Comment: It's actually not marked at all. I tried marking it with `[HttpGet]`, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Consider stuffing the URL in an html data attribute then obtaining it with jQuery. You already do something similar with the id value.

```
<button id="btnAdmDel" data-url="@Url.Action("deleteAdm", "SuperUser")">Click</button>

$('#btnAdmDel').click(function () {
    var id = $('#tbSeek').val();
    var url = $(this).data("url");
    $.get(url + "/" + id, function (data) {
        $('#partials').html(data);
    });
});
```

This lets the Razor helper resolve the URL for you while keeping your javascript Razor-free where mixing the two often leads to an unreadable mess.

Comment: I tried something like it, but the javascript code can't "see" the variable declared outside `$.get`

Comment: You are using Razor Url.Action helper strictly in the view html code. The script block obtains the resolved url via the `data-url` attribute.

Comment: Perhaps you are omitting an important detail from your question. Do you have any script errors on the debug console? Is the route to "SuperUser/deleteAdm/x" returning a successful HTTP STATUS code?